# SAXReader.read returns null only during debug mode

Tags: java, dom4j

I am using org.dom4j.io library to read in XML responses from a web service. The code runs correctly as expected during normal execution. The problem is when I run in debug mode the SAXReader always returns a null document. (This is running as a TestNG Test in Eclipse). Relevant code:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
SAXReader mySAXReader = new SAXReader();
InputStream myInputStream = responseEntity.getContent();
actualResponse = mySAXReader.read(myInputStream);
```

If I put in a print statement and run normally, actualResponse contains the expected XML response. If I run the code in debug mode actualResponse is always NULL.

Comment: Sorry, that was accidental, here: http://testng.org/doc/index.html

Comment: It just sounds like there might be some configurations which are specific to debug/run. But in all honesty I've never used TestNG.

Comment: I checked my Run Configuration / Debug Configuration settings and they are identical.